# 2-norm of matrix is preserved by orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

We need to show that the euclidean norm for matrices are preserved under multiplications by orthogonal matrices as follow:

$$ \|QAP\|_2=\|A\|_2$$ , where $P$ and $Q$ are square orthogonal matrices.

Here is what I have tried:

$$\|PAQ\|_2=sup_{x,\|x\|=1} \|PAQx\|_2= \langle PAQx,PAQx\rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}=x^TQ^TA^TP^TPAQx=x^TQ^TA^TAQx$$. Now I don't know how to continue.

Comment: if you are aware that the "2 norm" is just the biggest singular value of $A$ (i.e. Schatten $\infty$ norm), then the result should be immediate because in reals multiplication by an orthogonal matrix doesn't change singular values

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that this has been answered before but I can't find a suitable answer.

If $P$ is orthogonal then $\|x\| = \|Px\|$ for all $x$. Also, $PB(0,1) = B(0,1)$.

Then  $\sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \|QAPx \| = \sup_{\|y\| \le 1} \|QAy \| = \sup_{\|y\| \le 1} \|Ay \|$.